# My Site Video upload speed is slower than other site?

Tags: web-applications, file-upload, performance, infrastructure

I have uploaded a same file to two different sites it had 30% time difference what are all the major factors affecting this? and what should i do to increase my sites upload speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sites reside on two different servers, the following factors may weigh in:

- **Old server** - Old hardware=slower
- **High server load -** More load=slower server.
- **Load balancing (more than one server) -** More servers=faster response.
- **Available bandwidth -** Low bandwidth=slower download. This could be normal or you might have routers that are underperforming.
- **Number of routers between the server and the Internet -** Each hop takes time.
- **Distance between server and your browser -** Longer=slower (more jumps between servers).
- **Internet load -** If the servers in between you and the server are under load, it's getting slower.
- **High load on your ISP's network -** More traffic=slower download

Make sure to host your sites with a reliable hosting service.